# Difference Between How Dictionary ContainsKey Handles Transform.Forward and New Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm in the process of setting up a grid system for a turn based game. The grid is stored as a
Dictionary<Vector3,Node> where Node is a class that handles where it is available for units to occupy, etc.

One unit that I've created spawns a projectile based on where the player is (aiming towards), and in subsequent turns the projectile moves in its transform.forward direction, which shouldn't change after it's been instantiated. If the projectile's next target Node is available, it moves to that Node; otherwise, it destroys itself and does damage to the player. Here's the code (held in a "Linear Movement" component on the projectile) that is responsible for checking if the projectile can move to the next Node:

```
grid = GridManager.instance.grid; //Caching a reference to the grid from its singleton

//Other stuff

public bool NextNodeIsWalkable { get
{
    if (!grid.ContainsKey(moveTarget)) return false;
    return grid[moveTarget].isWalkable;
} }
```

This is all well and good; it's pretty simple code. The problem comes in when we set moveTarget:

```
private Vector3 moveTarget { get
     {
            return Vector3.right * transform.position.x + Vector3.forward * transform.position.z + moveDirection;
     } }
```

moveDirection itself is set as moveDirection = transform.forward in OnEnable.

In some cases - which seem to me to be completely random, though they are always when the arrow is moving horizontally and never vertically - the grid.ContainsKey(moveTarget) check returns false even when there is an available Node, causing the projectile to explode.

There are a few puzzling behaviors here.

1. As alluded to above, if the projectile is moving vertically, it always behaves as expected.
2. In some cases, if I switch the positions of the player and the enemy which generates the projectiles (so that the projectile is moving right instead of left, or vice versa), the grid.ContainsKey(moveTarget) check behaves as expected, finding a Node in the dictionary, and telling the projectile to move.
3. If I change the variable moveDirection to be a hardcoded Vector3 in the given direction, it *always* behaves as expected, finding the Node in the dictionary which it wasn't finding before, even in the cases where the transform.forward Vector3 is identical to the hardcoded Vector3 I've put in. I think this is really the crux of my question - why would these behave differently? Where am I going wrong?

I can post screenshots of my VisualStudio debugging if that would be helpful. Thank you for taking the time to read this. I am going insane and this has rocked me to my core.

Comment: it seems you are using a Vector3 as a key to your dictionary. I am surprised this works at all. Did you consider using Vector3Int instead? It is quantised to integer values, when using Vector3 your dictionary won't find a key if its different at all, and floats will have a tendency to produce sligtly different values as you move away from (0,0,0)

Comment: Yes, I was able to solve my problem by using Vector3Int.RountToInt(moveDirection) - I think I've been able to get away with this so far since all nodes and displacements have been strictly orthogonal.